# How to retrive document ID from firebase(not firestrore)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to get document Id from realtime database,not firestore?
I need to get list of document ids via javascript

Comment: Post the JSON structure of your database and explain what exactly you  need to get.

Comment: The Real Time Database does not have document Id's. The RTDB uses key: value pairs similar to a Dictionary (it's called a Snapshot). The compariable term is key. See [Structure Your Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) for some good reading. You can generally get it like this `var childKey = childSnapshot.key;`

Comment: thank you, now I will know about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set configuration and initialize firebase:

```
  var firebaseConfig = {
      //You can get the necessary information in you project console
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

This will give you the keys of your reference children:

```
var myRef = firebase.database().ref(//path to you data);
var keys = [];  
myRef.once("value", function(snapshot){
  documents=Object.keys(snapshot.val());
  for(d in documents){
    keys.push(documents[d]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
 this.productsAndKey = firebase.database().list('path')
                      .snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(changes =>
    changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
  )
);
```

and you will have the structure of you data along the firebase key

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).